# matlab unable to write to text file

Tags: matlab, text, fopen, fwrite, fclose

I am trying to write to a text file "result.txt" using the following matlab code in ubuntu 13.10

```
fid = fopen('/home/gaurav/matlab/OCR/result.txt','wt');
fprintf(fid,'asdasd');
fclose(fid)
```

I have changed the permission of file to 777, but nothing is happening.

I changed the 3rd line to

```
fprintf(fid,'%s','asdasd');
```

it worked, but now I changed it to

I am sorry it worked the first time, but after modifying it

```
fid = fopen('result.txt','wt+');
s='Allison Jones';
d='Development  ';
fprintf(fid,'%s\n',s);
fprintf(fid,'%s\n',d);
fclose(fid);
clc;clear;
```

the file is not being modified.

Comment: have a look at the documentation of `fprintf`, you need to specify a `'formatSpec'` - and `'asdasd'` isn't anything.

Comment: @thewaywewalk please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using only the file name in

```
fid = fopen('result.txt','wt+');
```

use the complete directory path

```
fid = fopen('/home/gaurav/matlab/OCR/result.txt','wt+');
```